# Distributed database for tree structured data?

Tags: tree, nosql, neo4j, hierarchical-data, couchbase

I'm looking for a database that is designed to handle tree structured data. I've looked into Neo4j and it's nice, but it doesn't really support sharding. Couchbase on the other hand isn't really built for a single tree of data (from my understanding).

A tree of data is theoretically really easy to split between servers whereas a complete graph isn't. I don't need the benefits of a full graph as much as I need the ability to split the big dataset dynamically. The full dataset won't fit on a single server.

The functions i need are (explained as if it were a normal computer file system):

1. Select every node in some "folder" excluding "sub-folders"
2. Split database (and load) between servers with redundancy

The system load will be mostly reads (approximately 90%).

Thanks!

Comment: How big is your dataset? You may be prematurely optimizing your code before it needs it. Did you have an idea of what you can split on? You say that a tree is ripe for sharding, but can you elaborate, as I can see many trees having the same issues as graphs would have with sharding.

Comment: http://thinkaurelius.com/2013/03/30/titan-server-from-a-single-server-to-a-highly-available-cluster/ Check out Titan. Graph database made to scale - and even shard.

Comment: @Nicholas It will be about 1GB-100TB but I want it to scale all the way up. I could just split at any "folder level" i.e. put half the "folders" on one server and the other half on another, right?

Comment: @ryan1234 would you mind answering as an answer instead of as a comment? :)

Answer (score 0):

I commented because I wanted to try and help and didn't think my link was really answer worthy. =)

I've been keeping an eye on Titan and it seems to be very bleeding edge right now. After reading the article (http://thinkaurelius.com/2013/03/30/titan-server-from-a-single-server-to-a-highly-available-cluster/) it seemed like they are using Cassandra in some capacity, so the scale of Cassandra is tightly bound to the scale of Titan.

From the article it seems that you don't have to explicitly shard the data. It will automatically distribute it for you when it reaches a certain size.

Here is another presentation about Titan and how it uses Cassandra:  http://blog.andreamostosi.name/2013/03/titan-distributed-graph-database/

Comment: What are the risks of using a bleeding edge solution?

Comment: If I were you I would immediately reach out to the guys at Titan and form a relationship. If you never talk to them, then you risk hitting some sort of bug and having no support/no insight into what's going on. The risk is that you'll write a ton of code against Titan and it goes under or becomes unusable.  Neo4j has the history behind it, but Titan might be the next best. This might seem like a cop out, but a lot of the bleeding edge stuff is on Twitter these days.  Follow @aureliusgraphs and ask them questions. I bet they answer!

Comment: Still no response from @aureliusgraphs. Since it's based on cassandra, does it have the same limits as cassandra? And how does cassandra know what to store on what server, to minimize graph traversal across servers?

Comment: they won't answer on twitter :(